# jQuery with "onkeypress" lag to make a change

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a span with a text in it that suppose to change constantly after I press something in my textbox.

```
<input type="text" class="response" onkeypress="return ChangeSpan()" id="how_many" name="how_many" placeholder="Enter how many..." />
```

and my jQuery:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function ChangeSpan() {
    var text = $("#how_many").val();
    $('#changeText').text(text);
}
</script>
```

it's working perfectly fine , but when I press let's say `"dfg"` , its only present `"df"` on the span. and only when I add the next charecter, it adds the `"g"`.

I want it to respond also to the last character, how do I do that ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You probably want to use [keyup](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.onkeyup).

You use jQuery and add the events inline? That is bad practice. Attach events using on.

```
$("#how_many").on("keyup", function(){ $('#changeText').text( this.value ); });
```

Difference between keyup, keydown, and keypress explained on [quirksmode](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/events/keys.html).

Comment: +1 for explanation of why this fixes things and discouraging event attributes.

Comment: It's still bad practice to use inline events even if you **don't** use a framework like jQuery.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah I might be a little late but actually using `keypress` is better than `keyup` because if you hold a key very long it will show up when you release it if you use `keyup`.

If you use `keypress` you'll directly see what you've typed but you've to use it as shown in the code below.

The only problem is that `keypress` won't recognize if you delete chars. So `keypress` is better but `keyup` should be also in use.

```
$("#how_many")
    .keypress(function(e) {
        var text = $("#how_many").val() + String.fromCharCode(e.which);
        $("#changeText").text(text);
    })
    .keyup(function(e) {
        var text = $("#how_many").val();
        $("#changeText").text(text);
    });​
```

Look at [this](http://jsfiddle.net/kajhD/) example. It's exactly the code before.

And [this](http://jsfiddle.net/kajhD/1/) example. It's the code before without using `keypress`.

Hold any character key in both examples while the text box is on focus. As you can see the first example reacts better.

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="text" class="response" onkeyup="return ChangeSpan()" id="how_many" name="how_many" placeholder="Enter how many..." />
```

Comment: An explanation of *why* this fixes it would be useful

Comment: Actually, it should be 'keyup' event that fires after the character has been generated, keypress is similar to key down, just fires after the key down but the character generates after the key has been released.

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you just use bindings? This should do it:

```
<input type="text" class="response" id="how_many" name="how_many" placeholder="Enter how many..." />



$(window).load(function(){
   $("#how_many").bind('focus blur keyup',function(){
     $('#changeText').text($(this).val());
   }); 
})
```

Comment: Note: current version of jQuery deprecates the use of "bind" in favor of "on"

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your event to keyup.  Here's an example:

http://jsfiddle.net/SHdTL/

Note: I'd recommend using jquery to assign your event listener as well rather than inline, but it's not pertinent to your issue.